# How to set visibility of GridView Columns in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Well i have a list of objects `List<UserDC>` now i would want to display this in some kind of grid so i tryed the `GridView`

```
GridView1.DataSource = list
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Well that did work but now i want to hide some columns but that does not seem to be so easy :

```
GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
GridView1.Columns(1).Visible = False
GridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
```

this just gives me a exception `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` how do i make it generate the columns before it displays the list so i can filter out those that i dont want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the GridView columns, you can use the **GridView_RowDataBoundEvent** and hide the unwanted columns.

You can hide the Column Header, Data Rows OR BOTH by checking the "RowType" property in this event.

Comment: To use the GridView_RowDataBoundEvent is a overkill.  Not sure you can really do that.  Using the property Visible is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Works OK for me.  Here is a suggestion for you to check.
Since this is VB .NET code, I assume you have VS 2005 or 2008.
Set a breakpoint at GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False

Using the Watch Window, create a watch for GridView1.Columns.  Expand "base", What is the value of "Count"?  It is likely to be ZERO, means you do not have any columns.  The may be the reason you have "ArgumentOutOfRangeException".

Is your data binding to "list" working?

Answer (score -1):

You can set your visible columns as :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Property 2" DataField="Property1" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Property 2" DataField="Property2" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

AutoGenerateColumns="false" disables exposing all properties/columns of the datasource. And BoundFields will map your properties to grids columns.